# Dart Set.from() vs Set.of()

Tags: dart, constructor, set

In dart, `Set` class has two different factory constructors `Set.from()` and `Set.of()`.
Their returned results are same of same type. Is there any use case difference between them ? How to decide which one to use ?

See output of this program:

```
void main() {
    List<int> myList = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5];

    Set<int> mySetFrom = Set.from(myList);
    Set<int> mySetOf = Set.of(myList);

    print("mySetFrom type: ${mySetFrom.runtimeType}");
    print("mySetFrom: ${mySetFrom}");

    print("mySetOf type: ${mySetOf.runtimeType}");
    print("mySetOf: ${mySetOf}");
}
```

Output:

```
mySetFrom type: _CompactLinkedHashSet<int>
mySetFrom: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
mySetOf type: _CompactLinkedHashSet<int>
mySetOf: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Dart, what's the difference between List.from and .of, and between Map.from and .of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320220/in-dart-whats-the-difference-between-list-from-and-of-and-between-map-from-a)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Differences revealed with type inheritance:

```
Set<Object> superSet = <Object>{'one', 'two', 'three'};
```

`Set.from()` constructor can be used to down-cast from superSet

```
Set<String> subSet = Set<String>.from(superSet); // OK
```

But `Set.of()` cannot

```
Set<String> anotherSubSet = Set<String>.of(superSet); // throws an error
// The argument type 'Set<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<String>'.
```

I think `Set.of()` constructor is preferable with exactly the same type because of better performance.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/misc/PnRwv6doLhU/cliiTXCJBQAJ) (it is about `List`, but applicable to `Set` too)

Lasse explained it well. In summary, use `iterable.toSet()` for better performance if the type doesn't change. Use `Set.from()` for changing type. Don't use `Set.of()` since it is basically subsumed by the new literal (unless you think `of` is more readable).

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at them:

[`Set.of`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/Set/Set.of.html):

> `Set<E>.of(Iterable<E> elements)`

[`Set.from`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/Set/Set.from.html):

> `Set<E>.from(Iterable elements)`

Do you notice a difference?

`Set.of` takes an `Iterable<E>` and `Set.from` takes an `Iterable` with no explicit type.  In other words, `Set.of` does stronger type-checking of its argument.  `Set.from` is older, and `Set.of` was added in Dart 2 when strong typing was added.  You usually should use `Set.of`.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32959 requests that the documentation be improved to clarify this.

Comment: You should use `Set.of` when you already have an iterable of `E`. You should use `Set.from` when you have some `Iterable<X>` which you happen to know contains only objects of type `E`.