# Dart: Sorting by length of a list in a list of lists

Tags: dart

I want a function that takes a list of lists. It should sort this list of lists, regardless of its type, by the length of each list within it.

I thought I could achieve this by using the function below, but I am getting type errors. `X is not a subtype of Y`. From my understanding, using `dynamic` means it can take any type, so what am I doing wrong?

```
List<List<dynamic>> sortByLength(List<List<dynamic>> lss) {
  final newLss = List.from(lss);

  return newLss..sort((a, b) => a.length.compareTo(b.length));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you accidentally converted a `List<List<dynamic>>` to a `List<dynamic>` and then tried to return that as a `List<List<dynamic>>` without a cast.

```dart
final newLss = List.from(lss);
```

This makes two mistakes:

1. It uses [`List.from` instead of `List.of`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50320220/) (or instead of `lss.toList()` or `[...lss]`).
2. It does not specify an explicit type for the `List`.

Combined, those mistakes give `newLss` a type of `List<dynamic>`.  Attempting to return `newLss` then fails because converting `List<dynamic>` to `List<T>` requires using [`List.cast`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/List/cast.html) to change the element type.

Comment: I opted for the `[...lss]` option, the purpose was just to clone it to avoid mutations, which I thought `List.from` did. Thanks for the corrections!

Comment: `List.from` does make a copy, but in a dynamically typed way which allows you to do down-casts like converting a `List<num>` containing only integers to a `List<int>` (fx. `List<int>.from(listOfNum.where((x) => x is int && x.isEven)`). That means that it cannot infer the list element type from the argument, and you should either write `List<List<dynamic>>.from` use `List.of` instead. The latter works with type inference, but cannot do downcasts.