# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<InvoiceItemDto>?'

Tags: json, flutter

I have this list JSON output

```
 "invoiceItems": [
          {
            "description": null,
            "id": "13",
          }
        ],
```

I use below code to convert it to `List<InvoiceItemDto>`

```
 invoiceItems: json['invoiceItems'].map((data) => InvoiceItemDto.fromJson(data)).toList(),
```

But it throws me error

```
 Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<InvoiceItemDto>?'
```

**invoice_item_dto.dart**

```
class InvoiceItemDto {
  final int? id;
  final String? description;    

  const InvoiceItemDto({
   this.id,
   this.description,
  });

  factory InvoiceItemDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return InvoiceItemDto(
      id: json['id'],
      description: json['address'],
    );
  }

  InvoiceItemEntity toInvoiceItemEntity() {
    return InvoiceItemEntity(
      id: id,description: description);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add full code of root model

Comment: I need the code which includes `invoiceItems: json['invoiceItems'].map((data) =>InvoiceItemDto.fromJson(data)).toList(),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `List.from`

```dart
invoiceItems: List.from(json['invoiceItems'].map((data) => InvoiceItemDto.fromJson(data)));
```

Comment: yes,this worked ! May I know what's the reason?

Comment: [In Dart, what's the difference between List.from and .of, and between Map.from and .of?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50320220/10157127)