# Flutter / dart json encoding and decoding not casting dynamic types

Tags: json, flutter, dart, codec

```
_CastError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast)
```

I receive this error when attempting to decode a json string back into the list of objects from which it was created. I don't understand why it struggles to cast this; the underlying dynamic type is clearly an integer. Here is the code below, edited to be more concisely related to the issue.

```
class Obj extends Equatable {
  final List<int> scheduledTimes;
  final bool active;
...
Obj.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : scheduledTimes = json['scheduledTimes'] as List<int>,
        active = json['active'] as bool;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
    map['scheduledTimes'] = scheduledTimes;
    map['active'] = active;
    return map;
  }
...
```

I encoded this using `json.encode` (which triggered toJson()) and then immediately attempted to `json.decode` this but it failed with the error:

```
_CastError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast)
```

Comment: Replace `json['scheduledTimes'] as List<int>` with `(json['scheduledTimes'] as List<dynamic>).cast<int>()` That tells the runtime "you will find that that dynamic thing you have (json['scheduledTimes']) is a List<dynamic>" (it agrees because it tells you it is in the error), "but I can assure you that each of the dynamics in that list is an int - so you can think of it as such - and are permitted to throw if I'm wrong"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because Dart is strongly typed and modifications to collections are shallow by default. So when you tried this:

```
scheduledTimes = json['scheduledTimes'] as List<int>
```

It is, unfortunately insufficient for casting a collection like List because the runtime type for the collection has already been set. Instead you need to create a new list of the type desired from the original (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.from.html):

```
scheduledTimes = List<int>.from(json['scheduledTimes']);
```

or use something like the cast method (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html):

```
scheduledTimes = json['scheduledTimes'].cast<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `List.from`

```dart
Obj.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : scheduledTimes = List.from(json['scheduledTimes'] ) ,
        active = json['active'] as bool;
```

Comment: Thanks - had already applied the method I mentioned in my posted answer. Do you know why these two methods work, but the original method did not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50320220/10157127

Comment: You need to include the type argument with: List<T>.from()

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand why this fails to cast as everything in the above syntax looks good to me, but I did find a fix for this which makes dart happy to do the casting.

Replacing

```
Obj.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : scheduledTimes = json['scheduledTimes'] as List<int>,
        active = json['active'] as bool;
```

with

```
Obj.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : scheduledTimes = [...json['scheduledTimes']],
        active = json['active'] as bool;
```

made it work without issue. Frankly, this notation seems to me like it would give the compiler *less* information on types, but whatever.

If someone out there knows why my original didn't work, I'd be very curious to hear.